# 2DRaycast is shooting slightly in wrong directions

Tags: unity, 2d, raycasting

I wanted just a simple 2DRaycast, which points from my character to my mousePointer. So I found the following code in the Internet, most people seem to use it like that. So I tried it, but it isn't working for me like it is supposed to do, check the screenshot below. The direction is kinda weird, so I tried some variants of the variables and tried with Normalize, which didn't solve the problem.

```
    Vector2 test = new Vector2 (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition).y);
    Vector3 test1 = (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition));
    //test.Normalize ();
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (transform.position, test);
    Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, test, Color.red);
```

I tested both variables, test and test1, same things happen, even with Normalize and without it. The following Screenshot shows, what happens (The red thing is the mouse pointer).

[image]

Edit:

Solution:

```
    Vector2 test = new Vector2 (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition).y);
    Vector3 test1 = (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition));
    //test.Normalize ();
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (transform.position, test1 - transform.position);
    Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, test1 - transform.position, Color.red);
```

I use now the second variable, because we need the Vector3 here, because we substract with Transform.position which is a Vector3.

Comment: Are you using the editor for Linux, Mac, or Windows? I've seen this problem first hand in the Linux editor. In any case, try switching the resolution to the `free aspect` setting and see if that works out for you.

Comment: Windows, can you give me a hint where I can find that?

Comment: Okay I got it and it is already on "free aspect"

Comment: As an aside,  `new Vector2 (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition).y);` is a bit clunky. You can do the same thing with `(Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)` without calling the function twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Physics2D.Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html)  documentation states :

Parameters:

**origin**  The point in 2D space where the ray originates.

**direction**   Vector representing the direction of the ray.

**distance**    Maximum distance over which to cast the ray.

...

so try :

```
 RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (transform.position, test-transform.position);
```

where

```
test-transform.position
```

is the ray direction

Comment: Wow thanks, that's simple, I edit the question and mark your answer as correct thnks